# How to retrieve email from email server using IMAP?

Tags: imap, mail-server

I'm developing managing email server using vb.net and asp.net
i need sample or open source component to retrieve emails from my email server (get new messages - all mesgs - delete msg - copy msg - etc ) using IMAP Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject has [a](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IMAP_sync.aspx) [couple](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx) you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this open source project: http://mailsystem.codeplex.com

.NET Framework doen't include imap4 support yet.